# Loading user data in Angular Ionic app not working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am new to Angular Ionic, I have a simple app build with Angular Ionic framework which loads user profile data using rest api. The problem is data is never shown in the app after user clicks the profile tab the loading modal keep showing. The api works fine in postman as well as in browser and profile data is sent correctly by the back-end.

This is my profile.page.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ProfileService } from '../services/profile.service';
import { Profile } from './profile.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.page.scss'],
})
export class ProfilePage implements OnInit {
  profile$: Observable<Profile[]>;

  constructor(
    private profileService: ProfileService,
    private loadingCtrl: LoadingController
  ) {}

  async ngOnInit() {
    const loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create({ message: 'Loading..' });
    loading.present();

    this.profile$ = this.profileService.getProfile().pipe(
      tap((profile) => {
        loading.dismiss(); //this is never dismissed and keep loading
        return profile;
      })
    );
  }

}
```

This is the service file profile.service.ts which actually sends the api request to the back-end

```
import { Profile } from '../profile/profile.model';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ProfileService {
  apiUrl = 'http://localhost/myapp/public/api';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getProfile(): Observable<Profile[]> {
    return this.http.get<Profile[]>(`${this.apiUrl}/profile/1`); //fetches the profile with id: 1
  }
}
```

I don't get an error in the console just loading... modal keep showing forever. Any idea what could be the wrong in the code?

Comment: It should work without any issues, [check here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic6-angular13-smj12z), can you please simulate the issue here and provide a stackblitz to me? My guess, is it works fine when the profile is visited first, and on the next visits it does not work.

Comment: Also I have another page which has exact same code and it works fine! Could it be the CORS issue, if so it should give error message in console right?

Comment: Any error should be printed in the console. Just cross-check by checking the network tab as well. to see what's going on with the network call.

Comment: You need to subscribe to observable for it to work. Check if you get some response with a subscription : this.profile$ = this.profileService.getProfile().subscribe(data => console.log(data); loading.dismiss(););